# iOS Safari Action Extension Transparent Background

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension

For iOS Safari Action Extension, is there a way to present a view controller that will overlay Safari with transparent background?

Currently, It only shows a gray background when I turn the view's opacity to 0. It isn't showing the safari underneath the extension.